# How to hide 'id' in url and show nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

To access a dashboard this is the url: `http://localhost:3000/dashboards/1`
I want to hide `id`and show nothing in the url to do this: `http://localhost:3000/dashboards/`
I see another questions but all of it show to substitute `id` for `name` for example.
How can I just hide the id?

Comment: Your question generates many more questions from our side - what is dashboard. Is it user related? Are there many dashboard for each user if so or one for a whole application? How do you define your current routes? Can you use singular resource? Potato?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a new route in `routes.rb`. If you're using `resources :dashboards` then that path is already defined and conventionally reserved as an index to list all available objects. Something like this should work:

```
get 'dashboards' => 'dashboards#show'
```

Note also that if you need the id in the controller you can no longer rely on params to grab the id as it's no longer in the url and available. You will have to use sessions instead.

Answer (score 1):

Map the controller as a `resource` instead of `resources`. In your `routes.rb` file change

```
resources :dashboards
```

to

```
resource :dashboard
```

This assumes your controller is called `DashboardsController`. If not, pass the appropriate controller name.

```
resource :dashboard, controller: 'whatever_controller'
```

You may also want to restrict to the show action only, unless you have other actions.

```
resource :dashboard, only: [:show]
```

This will create the route

```
GET /dashboard
```

If you don't limit the actions, you'll get also

```
GET /dashboard/new
POST /dashboard
PATCH /dashboard
DELETE /dashboard
```